# How so I show json in a partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I have a javascript graph from a rails app. When I click a circle in the graph it tells me what the name of the user it represents is. I then want the app to find more information from the database table that relates to that user name.
I have got pretty far but don't seem to be able to see the result in a partial.

The controller is correctly triggered to query the database in response to a javascript onclick

```
def show
    @user = User.find_by name: params[:name]
    puts @user
    render json: @user
end
```

How to I then put the json this in a partial _profile.html.erb

```
<div>Hi I'm a partial</div>
<div class='profile-content'></div>
```

and then show the partial in a page called graph/data.html.erb

and show

Comment: jbuilder is built into rails: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Comment: How to I change the controller instruction to make sure the json shows in the partial?

Comment: Sorry, disregard comment above. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the show.js.html. So:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by name: params[:name]
  puts @user
  render json: @user
end
```

becomes:

```
def show
 @user = User.find_by name: params[:name]
end
```

Since your request is a JS request, then it will automatically ask for `show.js.html'. In this file:

```
$('.profile-content').inner_html("<%= @user.to_json %>");
```

What I would do is create a partial: `_user_details` and in here lay out `@user` how I'd like it to appear, then populate `.profile_content`` with that....so:

`_user_details.html.slim`

```
.user-details
 = @user.name
 = @user.phone_number
```

Then call that partial:

```
$('.profile-content').inner_html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'user_details')) %>");
```